# Set a link equal to the last clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a link that will return to a specific link that equals that of a link clicked on a main page.

Such that:

```
<a href="link.html" onclick="set this link to memory" target=home></a>
<a href="a memory of that other link" target=home></a>
```

The idea is that pages within an iframe can have links that users can follow while staying on the main page and the ability to return to original page that was inserted on that frame from a central link on the main page.

Thanks for everyone's help.  I researched this quite a bit and tried to use javascript and jquery but I am far too novice to make anything work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That question is unclear. There is no code and no HTML markup to help get the idea you are trying to explain.

Comment: Is this iframe on same domain as the page it is in? If not you can't access anything inside it. Beyond that this whole question is hard to follow

Comment: The iframe will be on the same domain the page is in.  I tried the href= javascript history.go(-#) but that has to be an exact number.  For instance to tell it go back to the original link you have to have the exact number of pages away the user has gone.  I do not want a simple back button but I want a button that will send them to the original link.

Comment: Also sorry, I did not know that if you wrote html in free text it would hide it.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to store the original iframe `src` on page load? Then reset that src ?

Answer (score 2):

**Only try this:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.memLink = ['link.html', this];" target=home>Copier Link!</a>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href=window.memLink[0]; this.onclick();" target=home>Dynamic Link!!</a>
```

[Try this Online!!](http://jsfiddle.net/xt7gabcL/11/)

Comment: **tip (Extra descriptions):**
if you want that clicking on the link1 be done normally, this link redirects you to dest page (link.html)! and in that case **link2 will not exists** for using saved info in window (memLink) or user can click on it. (If you want it, you can use cookie for save the link (instead of adding it to window) or etc..). That's why  I've deleted original href of the link1.

Comment: Thanks, that is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So basically I developed a workaround.  Instead of using the reload the frame function ,which stops working once you navigate away from the src, I link to another page that contains a frame with the contents being the desired src.  This way they can navigate to that page within the frame as far as they want and will always be able to return to the original page by refreshing the parent frame with the link I provided.  This should work for now.  However, this means that for every page I do this with I will have to create 2 pages to host one desired link within my pages that are to be navigated within iframes.  Hopefully there will be some simpler way to do this and hopefully it won't cause problems on mobile platforms when I start designing the pages for that purpose.